# Choosing a title of academic article about theoretical comparison and implementation

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

First, I am not looking for title suggestions. I am wondering if there is a proper expression that express very well the content of my paper. The article theoretically compares between four algorithms and nominate one of them as the best and implement it. I found many use `comparative analysis` but these article compare and implement all of the algorithms. Does it apply to my situation? What alternatives could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Selection of an algorithm for … "

> **[selection](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/selection)** noun [mass noun]
>   **1** the action or fact of carefully choosing someone or something as being the best or most suitable

Use case:

> Selection of an algorithm to generate a pseudostochastic stationary process …
>   Selection of an algorithm for the diffusion process.
>   Selection of an Algorithm for the Antibody-Antigen Reaction in Gels.